# Dimension filter in Spreadsheets (GA4 addon)

Tags: spreadsheet, dimension, google-analytics-4

At the moment I am struggling to filter my data on the specific dimension sourceMedium.

| Report Name | gads-conversions |
| --- | --- |
| Property ID | properties/xxxx |
| Start Date | 2023-01-01 |
| End Date | yesterday |
| Metrics | conversions:calculation, conversions:quotation, conversions:purchase, purchaseRevenue |
| Dimensions | sourceMedium, yearMonth |
| Metric Filters |  |
| Dimension Filters |  |
| Order |  |
| Limit | 1000 |
| Spreadsheet URL |  |
| Skip Report |  |

In the dimension filters I have tried multiple filters but none of them is working. Each time the report is generated it shows me all the data.
I have tried:

- sourceMedium__CONTAINS__google
- sourceMedium==google

And some other combinations but none of them is working. I find barely any information only that talks about this specific issue so I have no idea what to do.

Here the filtering is done through JSON markup but I'm working from a Google Spreadsheet with the GA4 addon: https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/

It would be greatly appreciated if you can help me out!